# in script code how to get data from ViewData in cshtml

Tags: javascript, .net

i want to get a list from ViewData,then trun the list to a var in the script ,so the other function in script can use the var;
i have search and do something to try do it,

```
<script>
      var t = {};
        @{foreach (var firstName in (ViewData["tags"] as List<Tag>))
          {

          @Html.Raw(firstName.Id);
        }
        }
</script>
```

in the html i can see the result is what i want.
but when i change it like this

```
t.Id=@Html.Raw(firstName.Id)
```

it will say t is not exist,welcome any suggestions,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store data from ViewData into a JavaScript object then try to implement your code in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = [];
@foreach (var d in (ViewData["tags"] as List<MvcApplication1.Models.Test>))
{
    <text>
        var obj = {};
        obj.Id = "@d.Id"
        obj.Name = "@d.Name"
        data.push([obj]);
    </text>
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: @Mamum thanks ,it works.but i can not understand the <text>,can you give some talks about this.

Comment: Even I am not sure about that. But I take that as just a helping tag to write some JavaScript code inside razor.

Comment: Here is some explanation I have found: "The <text> tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the <text> block as content, and to not render the containing <text> tag element (meaning only the inner contents of the <text> element will be rendered – the tag itself will not).  This makes it convenient when you want to render multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element.". Link : https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax